# Why don't we say "please" (that often)?

Tags: tefilla, words

The week day Shmoneh Esrei prayer has a series of requests during which we ask Hashem for many of our needs. In my siddur (Tefilla Hashalem) there is a subtle change made in the texts of 1 of the brachot, adding in a word not found in my Artscroll.

In the prayer for the righteous (al hatzadikkim) my siddur reads "יהמו נא רחמיך" while the Artscroll omits the "na."

In the siddur Shiloh, that "na" is present as is one in the prayer for redemption (re'ei), "ראה נא בענינו" which is missing from both my siddur and the Artscroll.

I understand that the texts are sometimes variable, though I'm used to seeing shifts only in v'lamalshinim, but my question is not about these local changes. I am wondering, why is the presence of "please" so infrequent? Is there something special about these blessings that would mandate saying please? Isn't that something that should be in our every request? Should we say please when we ask for healing or intelligence or the arrival of a Moshiach?

Comment: FTR Some versions of Artscroll have נא present in both of those locations. I believe that is the case in the Yitzchak Yair HaShalem version (the all-Hebrew one), but I don't have it with me right now.

Comment: Technically נא means “now” rather than “please,” conveying a sense of urgency rather than politeness in the request.

Comment: You can extend the question to bracha 11, 13, 17 for , for נא, for ,במהרה . In the current nusach sfard there are several na and numbers, mehera

Comment: I revise my previous comment, as evidence contradicts me. It's there in [Machzor Vitry](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=add_ms_27200_f037v), at some places [it's there](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=266) in R' Emden's siddur, while in others [it's omitted](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=270). R' Heidenheim consistently omits them. See also רחם-נא in the three faceted blessing.

Comment: @DonielF the Artscroll (Ahavat Shalom edition) says (page 727) that it means "please" so I'm relying on that, for better or worse.

Comment: @Daniel: the יצחק יאיר siddur doesn't have נא in either of those phrases, (I just checked) but I'm near-certain Artscroll's all-hebrew nusach sefard (תפילת שלמה) does, and I would presume that their English nusach sefard (סידור עץ חיים) does as well. (I've noticed that their nusach Ashkenaz siddurim for Israel (נר נפתלי) lean slightly toward nusach sefard in some ways, so they may as well.)